# Disable specific labels in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I tryed to disable some specific labels in a column charts in Highcharts. But i only can disable all labels or non. I search a bit in the internet and found commands like "labels"->"enabled" or "visible", but it won´t work. 
This is my code for a bar, where i want to disable the label.

```
{
  "color":"#ffff77",
  "x":"0.7",
  "pointWidth":"7",
  "labels":{
    "enabled":false
      },
  "dataLabels":{
    "enabled": false
  }    
}
```

My question is, if it is possible to disable just specific labels.
PS: I use Highcharts in Grafana.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assumed that you are asking about the dataLabels - so each label could be disabled inside the data array where specific point is defined.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9zdc2pnu/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

  series: [{
    data: [43934, 52503, 57177, {
      y: 69658,
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
      }
    }, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175],
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true
    }
  }]
});
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.data.dataLabels

---

### EDIT

After getting more information - to disable specific labels for axis you can use the **labels.formatter** callback or find and hide the specific label in the **render** callback.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rzskvuj9/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.labels.formatter

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render

Comment: no, i know how to disable dataLabels, i meant the normal labels on the xAxis or yAxis

Comment: It works for the Axis with numbers, but the problem is, it won´t work for axis with words. I tryed it with the value of the bar, with no success.

Comment: @BS1010 so could you reproduce your case on some online editor which I could work on?

Comment: I am afraid that the code which you have shared doesn't contain the data. https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2hacmzwp/

Comment: You mean the data for the values? https://jsfiddle.net/BS1010/56ers91g/3/

Comment: yes, I would like to see how your chart looks like, but currently is impossible.

Comment: I get the data from an SQL databank, because it´s live data from industries maschines.     the bar where i want to disable the label is a fixed value (37)

Comment: So could you reproduce your case with fixed sample data, like here: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/adnw0upz/ and describe which label should be disabled?

Comment: I should like to disable all of the Contract-Labels

Comment: Please check this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/stzLgwcv/

Comment: It works very well thank you, i saw i had over all the time the little mistake, that i forgot a comma and to put in the needed script. But thank you very much ;D